# Unknown number of entry in an object type

Tags: typescript, object, types

```
export interface TitleBrickValues {
  title: EditableBrickField<string>;
  description: EditableBrickField<string>;
  links: EditableBrickField<EditableLink[]>;
}
```

or

```
export interface TeasersBrickValues {
  title: EditableBrickField<string>;
  contents: EditableBrickField<EditableLink[]>;
}
```

or

```
export interface DynamicTeasersValues {
  title: EditableBrickField<string>;
  description: EditableBrickField<string>;
  dynamicContents: EditableBrickField<EditableLink[]>;
}
```

And many similar types.

Basically they all look to be

```
export interface DummyValues {
 
  randomKey: EditableBrickField<any>;
  // unknown number of keys that follow the same pattern
}
```

I tried to define it on the parent type AnyBrick under the prop values as follow:

```
export interface AnyBrick {
  id: string;
  technicalName: TechnicalNames;
  patternId: string;
  layoutId: string;
  context: BrickContext;
  anchor: string;
  values: Record<string, EditableBrickField<any>>;
  outOfDate: MediasList[] | null;
  saveStatus: SaveStatus;
  status: number;
  isDiffNewBrick: boolean;
  wordsCount: number;
}
```

But TypeScript complains:

```
TS2430: Interface 'DynamicTeasersBrick' incorrectly extends interface 'AnyBrick'.   Types of property 'values' are incompatible.     Type 'DynamicTeasersValues' is not assignable to type '{ [key: string]: EditableBrickField<any>; }'.       Index signature for type 'string' is missing in type 'DynamicTeasersValues'.
```

How can I solve the AnyBrick's values prop type?

Answer (score 0):

With the help of Adetoyese Kola-Balogun I came across that solution:

```
type BrickValues = {
  [key in 'title' | 'description' | 'dynamicContents' | 'links']?: EditableBrickField<string | EditableLink[]>;
};

export interface AnyBrick {
  id: string;
  technicalName: TechnicalNames;
  patternId: string;
  layoutId: string;
  context: BrickContext;
  anchor: string;
  values: BrickValues;
  outOfDate: MediasList[] | null;
  saveStatus: SaveStatus;
  status: number;
  isDiffNewBrick: boolean;
  wordsCount: number;
}
```

Thanks!